# Datatables Jquery Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, datatable

I have an issue with the reinitialisation of my datatable. My code below works by pulling in a json from getOrderStatus.php and upon success of this puts all the json data into javascript variables and then from this i can set these variables to div tags and display the data i need on my webpage. However the Datatable cannot be reinititalised once the ajax loop runs and displays the following error message "DataTables warning: table id=mytable - Cannot reinitialise DataTable". I believe i need a way to kill the table and recreate it upon the ajax refresh however i cant seem to find a way to do this ?

```
     $(document).ready(function ajaxLoop(){

      $.ajax({ 

        url: 'getOrderStatus.php',                     // Url of Php file to run sql         
        data: "",                                      
        dataType: 'json',                              //data format      
        success: function updateOrder(data)               //on reciept of reply
        {
          var OrdersSubmitted = data.OrderStatus[0].SUBMITTED;     //get Orders Submitted Count
          var OrdersFulfilled = data.OrderStatus[0].FULFILLED;     //get Orders Fulfilled count
          var LastTransaction = data.LastTransaction[0];           //get Last Transaction


          //--------------------------------------------------------------------
          // 3) Update html content
          //--------------------------------------------------------------------
          $('#OrdersSubmitted').html(OrdersSubmitted);
          $('#OrdersFulfilled').html(OrdersFulfilled); //Set output html divs
          $('#mytable').dataTable({
                  "data": LastTransaction,
                  "aging": false,
                  "searching": false,
                  "columns": [
                      { "title": "ORDER_ID" }, // <-- which values to use inside object
                      { "title": "STATUS" },
                      { "title": "ACC_NUMBER" },
                      { "title": "SORT_CODE" }

                      ]
                    });


        setTimeout(ajaxLoop, 2000);
        } 

      });
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try using "bDestroy": true.

```
$('#mytable').dataTable({
                  "data": LastTransaction,
                  "aging": false,
                  "searching": false,
                  "bDestroy": true,
                  "columns": [
                      { "title": "ORDER_ID" }, // <-- which values to use inside object
                      { "title": "STATUS" },
                      { "title": "ACC_NUMBER" },
                      { "title": "SORT_CODE" }

                      ]
                    });
```

Another way is if you check if datatable is already init. on your table

```
var table = $('#mytable');
if ($.fn.DataTable.fnIsDataTable(table)) {
//It's already a datatable
  //clear and destroy
  table.dataTable().fnClearTable();
  table.dataTable().fnDestroy();

}


**It seems your are using latest datatable version:**
```

then option should be destroy:true (aging should be changed to paging):

```
 $('#mytable').dataTable({
                      "data": LastTransaction,
                      "paging": false,
                      "searching": false,
                      "destroy": true,
                      "columns": [
                          { "title": "ORDER_ID" }, // <-- which values to use inside object
                          { "title": "STATUS" },
                          { "title": "ACC_NUMBER" },
                          { "title": "SORT_CODE" }

                          ]
                        });
```

and  check on existing datatable would be:

```
if($.fn.DataTable.isDataTable("#myTable"))
{
$('#myTable').DataTable().clear().destroy();
}
```

Comment: Still get the same issue when i add "bDestroy" : true, unfortunatly

Comment: added another code block? which version if API you'r using?